# too high implementation for minSDK in build.gradle created by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I've just created my first Android Studio project. I chose **min SDK 15**. I'm worried why then compile SDK by default **is higher**.. Is it secure? Will my app run on devices with API 15 in this configuration? But the **real problem** occurred when I switched my compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 24. Errors everywhere and info that `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` is too high for my target SDK. So why on earth Android Studio put there so **high implementation** if the min SDK is **lower**?

**TL;DR:**
Why implementation is so high? Will it work in this configuration with min API?? Why Android Studio works like this?

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.q_back.audiocrator"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: You should really read [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) if you're confused about `compileSdkVersion` vs `minSdkVersion` vs `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: Yes, I read this, but there is nothing about dependencies and `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
`

Comment: There's a [paragraph](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#5737) specifically about Support Library dependencies and `compileSdkVersion`.

Answer (score 3):

Its ok, and in fact normal for the compileSDK to be bigger than the minimum.  The library version for the support version should match your compileSDK.  Either upgrade to 26, or downgrade the support library.

Comment: But what with devices with lower APIs? Will app work on them if `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'` is higher?

Comment: Yes.  That's what the minSDKVersion controls.  However if you use functions that were added between the two you'll crash when you use them (or you need to add a version check and not use them if the check fails).

Answer (score 1):

All android devices with SDK versions equal and above the minSDKVersion will be able to run the application.
it is best to use the same version of SDK tools as the version on your compileSDK, it won't really affect the devices that can run the applications. the major factor is that some Google APIs wont work on lower SDK levels.